# if x or y in LIST is always true even if it is not

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an if statement which always returns as true even if it is not.
I have a global list :
`NUMBERS_LIST = []`

Numbers get added to it via an API call, that works fine.

When it does the following:

```
def func():
    if 8 or 9 in NUMBER_LIST:
        return true
    elif 1 or 2 in NUMBER_LIST:
        return true
```

But for some reason, it always returns true on the first if statement, even if `NUMBER_LIST = [1]`

I debugged my program and can see that `NUMBER_LIST` does contain 1, it's type is int.
I tried doing int(8), converting both types to str but that did not fix my issue.
When I debugged and step through the program, it doesn't really tell me much, I am using Pycharm.

Comment: This probably should be closed as a duplicate; I answered only because the amount of confusion over how the `or` operator behaves in situations like these indicates that the similarity of `x or y == z` and `x or y in z` could be overlooked. (My vote would immediately close the question, hence my not voting.)

Comment: @NChauhan Kind of the same idea, but I don't think that would make a good duplicate in this case.

Comment: @chepner I think the duplicate I have suggested does answer the question as some answers point out you would use `any(x in list for x in values_to_check)` to see if any of the values are in the list.

Comment: It doesn't address what is wrong with the OP's code in the first place, though, which I think is important. The duplicate suggested by Ture Pålsson does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`or` does not distribute. What you have written is *not* equivalent to

```
if 8 in NUMBER_LIST or 9 in NUMBER_LIST:
```

which is what you want, but to

```
if 8 or (9 in NUMBER_LIST):
```

Since `8` is a truthy value, the containment operation is never evaluated.

Comment: Right ok, I understand what you said but how would you write it?

Comment: Just like I did in the first line.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for that.